# Measuring the "distance" between two multivariate distributions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, terminology, distance-functions

I'm looking for some good terminology to describe what I'm trying to do, to make it easier to look for resources.

So, say I have two clusters of points A and B, each associated to two values, X and Y, and I want to measure the "distance" between A and B - i.e. how likely is it that they were sampled from the same distribution (I can assume that the distributions are normal). For example, if X and Y are correlated in A but not in B, the distributions are different.

Intuitively, I would get the covariance matrix of A, and then look at how likely each point in B is to fit in there, and vice-versa (probably using someting like Mahalanobis distance).

But that is a bit "ad-hoc", and there is probably a more rigorous way of describing this (of course, in practice I have more than two datasets with more than two variables - I'm trying to identify which of my datasets are outliers).

Thanks!

Comment: Dunno why, but a Mantel test flashed in front of my eyes when I read your post.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is also the [Kullback-Leibler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) divergence, which is related to the Hellinger Distance you mention above.

Comment: can one calculate the Kullback-Leibler divergence of points without making an assumption of the underlying probability density the points came from ?

Answer (score 19):

Hmm, the [Bhattacharyya distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance) seems to be what I'm looking for, though the [Hellinger distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance) works too.

Comment: you mention Bhattacharyya and Helling then accept an answer speaking about KL... At the end what was your choice and why?

Comment: I believe it was KL divergence, but ... that was in 2010 and my memory is far from perfect.

Comment: ahah yes I guessed that, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 14):

Heuristic

- Minkowski-form
- Weighted-Mean-Variance (WMV)

Nonparametric test statistics

- 2 (Chi Square)
- Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS)
- Cramer/von Mises (CvM)

Information-theory divergences

- Kullback-Liebler (KL)
- Jensen–Shannon divergence (metric)
- Jeffrey-divergence (numerically stable and symmetric)

Ground distance measures

- Histogram intersection
- Quadratic form (QF)
- Earth Movers Distance (EMD)

Answer (score 10):

The most complete survey is provided in *[Statistical Inference Based on Divergence Measures](http://books.google.com/books?id=ziDGGIkhqlMC&pg=PA493&dq=Leandro+Pardo+Complutense+University,+Chapman+Hall+2006&hl=en&ei=Zm_VTOqGI8H6lwepsfn9CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Leandro Pardo, Complutense University, Chapman Hall 2006.

Answer (score 1):

Few more measures of "Statistical Difference"

- Permutation test (by Fisher)
- Central Limit Theorem & Slutsky’s theorem
- Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxin test
- Anderson–Darling test
- Shapiro–Wilk test
- Hosmer–Lemeshow test
- Kuiper's test
- kernelized Stein discrepancy
- Jaccard similarity
- Also, hierarchical clustering deals with similarity measures between groups. The most popular measures of group similarity are perhaps the single linkage, complete linkage, and average linkage.