# What's a good measure of distance between multinomial samples to build a phylogenetic tree?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multinomial-distribution, distance, archaeology

**Summary**: *I'm looking for a measure of distance between multinomial samples of four or more categories in order to build a phylogenetic tree. I considered using `log(1/CHI2(sample-1, sample-2))`, where CHI2 gives the p-value of the chi-square test between two samples of equal size. I'm not sure whether this makes sense though. What's a good measure of distance between two multinomial samples? Intuitively, I want to be able to say that some sample A is closer to B than to C, then scale this up to thousands of samples to build a phylogenetic tree of sample relatedness.*

Archaeologists have long theorised on the relatedness of tool collections coming from different sites, but they rarely use any statistical tests. I'm under the impression that a large number of what they describe as patterns, sometimes on hundreds of pages, is totally spurious. (Besides they might be missing actual patterns.) I am no expert in statistics, but I would be interested in identifying which tool collections --- multinomial samples I believe --- are significantly different from one another, and in quantifying these differences with a measure of distance, eventually to build a phylogenetic tree.

Following one typology (Laplace 1964), there are 85 primary stone tool types, which can be arranged into 14 categories, including for example, that of backed points (*pointes à dos*):
[image]

These categories are further arranged into 5 families: Burins (B), Endscrapers (G), tools with abrupt retouch (RA, including backed points), foliaceous ("fancy looking") tools (F), and the substrate (archaic-like, poorly-made tools, S).

To simplify things at first, I want to consider only four tool families (all except the rare F) from eight archaeological layers of the same site.
[image]

As a measure of distance between two layers, I tried using `log(1/p)` where p is the p-value of the two-sample chi-square test. Of course, the p-value depends on sample size, so I eliminated layers with a sample size lower than 200 (layer F) and treated all other layers as if they had a sample size of 214 (the lowest sample size above 200). But is not obvious to me this is the best measure of distance.

How may I get a measure of distance between multinomial samples, ideally without downsizing samples? A distance would have to be symmetric, and to avoid weird behaviour, I'd probably also want dist(sample1, sample3) <= dist(sample1, sample2) + dist(sample2, sample3). I'm aware of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4044/measuring-the-distance-between-two-multivariate-distributions) but am unsure what to do of it.

If I could get a distance function between multinomial samples, my next step would be to build a phylogenetic tree in R using the [neighbour joining method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_joining).

Comment: It's not a "distance" but something like the Kullback-Leibler divergence between the two probability distributions may check the box for the question asked in the title.

Comment: @gammer Thanks for your help! I am not convinced, however, that the Kullback-Leibler divergence (as I understand it) would help me, as it is both not symmetric D_kl(P|Q) ≠ D_kl(Q|P) and does not obey the triangle inequality D_kl(P|R) ≰  D_kl(P|Q) + D_kl(Q|R). These are both essential to the idea of distance and essential to build a phylogenetic tree.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using a measure of distance similar to the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric). If the proportion of tools were the following

```
    Tool type | B    | G    |  T   | DT    | 
 Assemblage A | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.10 | 0.10  | 
 Assemblage B | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.25  |
```

the Wasserstein metric builds the cumulative frequencies:

```
    Tool type | B    | B +G |B+G+T |B+G+T+DT| 
 Assemblage A | 0.40 | 0.80 | 0.90 | 1      | 
 Assemblage B | 0.25 | 0.50 | 0.75 | 1      |
```

and adds up the absolute column differences: |0.40-0.25| + |0.80-0.50| + |0.90-0.75| + |1-1| = 0.60. This was not ideal, however, as the distance obtained in this way depended on the order of the columns.

I simply used the summed of absolute pairwise differences in the first table. The distance between assemblages A and B is then simply the sum of the absolute values of the differences in relative frequency of each tool type: |0.40 - 0.25| + |0.40 - 0.25| + |0.10 - 0.25| + |0.10 - 0.25| = 0.60.

This distance seemed more natural than the log(1/p) one. In the end the choice of distance did not seem to matter because both measures of distance were highly correlated, which was reassuring:

[image]

Comment: +1 but it would seem more natural to sum the squared differences in fractions (and then to take a square root, i.e. to compute root-mean-squared-difference), as opposed to sum the absolute values of the differences.

Comment: Also, if you want to go the chi-square idea, then it would seem more appropriate to take the value of chi-square statistic as the distance, as opposed to some arbitrary transformation of the p-value. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Example_chi-squared_test_for_categorical_data for how to compute the statistic (you'll see that it's related to the sum of squared deviations, that I suggested above). The value of the statistic does not depend on the sample size.